# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert x_n \rvert ^\frac{1}{n}$ when $x_{n+1}=3x_n + \frac{2}{x_n^2},x_1=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert x_n \rvert ^\frac{1}{n}$ when $x_{n+1}=3x_n + \frac{2}{x_n^2}, x_1=1$

I figured out that $x_n$ increases as n approaches infinity.
However, the power approaches 0 as n approaches infinity.
So, I thought the limit does not approach 0 because the base approaches infinity while the power approaches 0.

Any hint that I can get?

Comment: Since you know that $x_n \to \infty$, can you compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n=1}/x_n$? And what does that say about the growth of $x_n$?

Comment: I added one more thing, $x_1=1$ Does it change anything?

Comment: The right side ($\frac{2}{{x_n}^2}$) shall become negligible.

Comment: Is the ratio test equal to the root test in value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us notice that $3x_n\leq x_{n+1}\leq 3x_n+2$.
So $3^{N-1}\leq x_{N} \leq 3^{N-1}+3^{N-1}-1<2*3^{N-1}$. As $\lim_{n\to\infty} |3^{n}a|^{1/n}=3$ for any constant $a$, so our limit is also equals to $3$.

Comment: Simpler than mine. Sometimes a crude estimate is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! But too much crude for me!

Comment: But you don't need sharp estimate for limit counting)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that
$x_0 > 0$,
$x_{n+1}
=3x_n + \frac{2}{x_n^2}
\gt 3x_n
$
so
$x_n > 3^n x_0$.

Also
$x_{n+1}
=3x_n + \frac{2}{x_n^2}
\lt 3x_n+\frac{2}{(3^nx_0)^2}
= 3x_n+\frac{2}{9^nx_0^2}
$
so
$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}
\lt \dfrac{x_n}{3^n}+\frac{2}{27^nx_0^2}
$.

Letting
$y_n = \dfrac{x_n}{3^n}$,
$y_{n+1}-y_n
\lt \frac{2}{27^nx_0^2}
$.

Summing
$y_m-y_0
=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}(y_{n+1}-y_n)
\lt \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{2}{27^nx_0^2} 
=\frac{2}{x_0^2}  \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{27^n} 
\lt \frac{2}{x_0^2}\dfrac{1}{1-1/27}
= \frac{27}{13x_0^2}
=c$
so
$y_m
\lt y_0+c
$
or
$\dfrac{x_m}{3^m}
\lt y_0+c
$
or
$\dfrac{x_m^{1/m}}{3}
\lt (y_0+c)^{1/m}
\to 1
$.

Therefore
$\lim_{m \to \infty} x_m^{1/m}
=3
$.

Comment: Thank you very much! A detailed solution helps me a lot!